# JSON object into kendo template

Tags: jquery, json, loops, kendo-ui, kendo-template

How can I create JSON into kendo template??

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template">
...
   # for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { #

                # var myJson= { #
                  # "ID" : data[i].ID, #
                  # "Name" : data[i].name, #
                  # "Description" : data[i].desc, #
                  # "C_ID" : $("#customers").data("kendoDropDownList").value(), #
                  # "isNew" : true#
                # } #
...
</script>
```

Comment: Question is not clear. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: i need create that json objects from every object obtained from data and next can use it ... actualy i always error for template but when I cut that code works .. so issues is with that variable and her definition

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the hash sign in the jquery selector:

```
$("#customers")
```

The template parser uses the # sign to mark the start/end of script code. To use a hash within a section of script it needs to be escaped with a double backslash like so:

```
$("\\#customers")
```